# How to write and run a LLVM X86 Machine Function Pass 2022

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I've been trying to write a machineFunctionPass in LLVM to emit the assembly corresponding to each LLVM IR instruction.

I've tried to follow [this mailing list thread](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-November/092139.html), but I haven't been able to get it to work, and nothing is outputted. I've also tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.kharghoshal.xyz/blog/writing-machinefunctionpass), but nothing gets outputted, and some header files had to be changed for it to even compile.

I've written a test pass that prints hello in `X86EmitMap.cpp`

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/MachineFunctionPass.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetIntrinsicInfo.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetMachine.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetOptions.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace llvm {
  FunctionPass *createX86EmitMap();
  void initializeX86EmitMapPass(PassRegistry &);
} // namespace llvm

namespace {
  struct X86EmitMap : public MachineFunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid

    X86EmitMap() : MachineFunctionPass(ID) {
      initializeX86EmitMapPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
    }
    StringRef getPassName() const override { return "emit map pass"; }

    virtual bool runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF) override;
  };
} // namespace

char X86EmitMap::ID = 0;
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(X86EmitMap, "emit map", "emit map pass", false, false)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(X86EmitMap, "emit map", "emit map pass", false, false)

FunctionPass *llvm::createX86EmitMap() { return new X86EmitMap(); }

bool X86EmitMap::runOnMachineFunction(MachineFunction &MF) {
  errs() << "\n\nhello\n\n ";
  return false;
}
```

My understanding of the process is:

1. Create file and add code to `llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86EmitMap.cpp`
2. Add `addPass(createX86EmitMap());` to `void X86PassConfig::addPreEmitPass()`
3. add `X86EmitMap.cpp` to the `CMakeLists.txt` in `lib/Target/X86`
4. add `FunctionPass *createX86EmitMap()` to `X86.h`
5. Build and run llc, which should print "hello"

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Or can you point me to a guide on how to write a backend pass that is up to date? I havent been able to figure it out from these links either:

https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html 
https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked a similar pass in X86TargetMachine.cpp, e.g. X86ReturnThunks pass.
Use grep to find all usages, it includes:

- ./lib/Target/X86/CMakeLists.txt, add into cmake compilation
- pass source file in X86 folder
- X86.h, 2 parts:

  1. declare function pass: FunctionPass *createX86ReturnThunksPass();
  2. declare init with registry: void initializeX86ReturnThunksPass(PassRegistry &);
- X86TargetMachine.cpp, 2 parts:

  1. initialize to registry: initializeX86ReturnThunksPass(PR);
  2. use it in backend compilation: addPass(createX86ReturnThunksPass());

Looks like you add the pass but you also need to registry it.